# How do i make a minecraft server mod?

Tags: server, minecraft-modding, modding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mods for Minecraft Server - how does it work?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/mods-for-minecraft-server-how-does-it-work)

I have made some minecraft client mods, but i've started a server a mounth ago and i want to make a mod for it, but i cant find any tutorial on the internet. How can then the other guys making those mods for minecraft server know how they are going to do? Do they try forward as i tryed or are they doing something else. I would be glad if someone could tell me how to do or find tutorials for me, couse I have tryed to find them in nearly a week of searching. But i guess im searching at the wrong spot of internet, what do i know :o

Comment: @Tetrad I don't think this is a duplicate - he is asking **how** to make a mod; not how you make a mod in your own game.

Comment: You should have a look at [bukkit](http://bukkit.org/) - it's a modified version of the minecraft server that supports mods.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson how is this answer in that question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/mods-for-minecraft-server-how-does-it-work/14877#14877 not an answer to Simon's question?

Comment: @Tetrad - I guess it should be OK (only this 'Mod API' is starting to become vaporware) - I guess it doesn't matter; my comment should be enough info for him to get started with modding right now.